# Фиксированная позиция при прокрутке

Tags: css, position, fixed

В шапке веб-страницы расположены якоря как меню. Шапка при прокрутке веб-страницы вниз получает фиксированную позицию. Если нажать на пункт меню, происходит переход к сноске закрывая заголовок сноски на высоту шапки. Как сделать прокрутку учитывая высоту шапки?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

      //check to see if we have scrolled past the original location of the sticky element
      if (windowTop > stickyTop) {

        //if so, change the sticky element to fised positioning
        $(".sticky").css({
          "position": "fixed",
          "top": 0
        });
      } else {
        $(".sticky").css({
          "position": "static"
        });
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="sticky"></header>
```

Comment: St1myL так будет пусто между блоками. Шапка 100px. Есть другой способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', ' a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top-50/* Вместо 50 можете подставить высоту вашей шапки
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.block{
  height:100vh;
}
.header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  background:#fff;
  height:50px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.header a{
 
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.blue{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
   <a href="#1">Sick of a tension</a>
   <a href="#2">Sick of a hunger</a>
</div>
<div class="block" id="1">
  <h1>Sick of a tension</h1>
</div>
<div class="block blue" id="2">
  <h1>Sick of a hunger</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое что можно сделать: это перед элементом с якорем создать пустой элемент с шириной шапки и перенести якоря на него: например:

```html
было
<h2 name="yakor1">заголовок 1</h2>
стало
<div name="yakor1" style="height="высота шапки"></div>
<h2>заголовок 1</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задайте body padding-top = высоте шапки

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/247602)

Comment: @Sublihim "не является ответом на вопрос" означает, что этот пост - не попытка ответа, а, например, уточняющий комментарий или уточнение. Очевидно, что это не так. Не стоит выбирать этот вариант ответа для тех постов, которые являются попытой ответа (пусть даже технически неполной или неверной).